# How to run start_cluster.sh in flink

Tags: apache-flink

I have downloaded in windows flinK-1.13.2. I am trying to start flink's cluster and it shows that `starting standalonesession daemon on host`. However, when I go to localhost:8081 it doesn't show something. Why is this happening? java version "15.0.1"

Comment: Please check the log files at the log directory and post relevant errors. Also are you able to `ping localhost`?

Comment: Flink only supports Java 8 and 11.

Comment: do you use  a docker image or downloaded binary compressed file? if you are using docker you may need to bind flink port into local with `-p` parameter: `docker run -p 8081:8081 -d <image name>`